# How to actually re-use UI layout elements?

Tags: android, android-layout

To make sure every UI element of the same type looks the same, I am trying to find a way to re-use layout elements for proper way. For example, my primary CTA button always has a rounded background, font, text size, spacing, color, etc.

I could use the `<include/>` tag like so:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/include_primary_button"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home_cta" />
```

with my `include_primary_button.xml` being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <Button
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
        fontPath="fonts/Roboto.ttf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="STUB!"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text" />
</merge>
```

Using the `<include/>` tag limits only the layout properties to be overridden. So for example setting the text of every button used, I need to `findViewById` in the activity/fragment and set the text programmatically. This annoys me, but can be overcome. But then retrieving the button from the activity (eg. `Button mButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_home_cta);`), the button is null. What is missing here?

And is there not an easier way to re-use elements? This really feels like a hassle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a style. For example

```
<style name="CustomButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/ButtonText</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/btn_primary</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_primary</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/btn_padding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/btn_padding</item>
    </style>

 <style name="ButtonText">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/arial</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_button</item>
    </style>
```

And then add it

```
<Button
            style="@style/CustomButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn" />
```

If you want to have a custom view you can always create a new class that will extend from whatever you want (ex, Button, View) which will have its own xml and then you would add it like so. (Here is a [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/142-android-custom-view-tutorial) for that. There are many on the interwebz)

```
<CustomView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: And even more, you can add everything in the custom style, even the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`

Answer (score 1):

Use styles. For simple use cases like the one you say custom styles will help.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you've got to know is the following:

> The `<include>` tag is not a real view, so `findByView` will not find
>   it. The @id attribute (and any other attributes you've set on the
>   include tag) gets applied on the root tag of the included layout
>   instead. [(source)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36954169#comment4)

Meaning that your id attribute gets transferred to the `<merge>` tag, which isn't a real view, hence why it can't be found. If you remove the `<merge>` tag, it should work.

Also, instead of creating that button in a layout file and including it, you could also create a custom `View` and then use that in your layout files. You can read more about creating a `View` [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view).